# Dynamic pie chart in Google Chart is not working

Tags: javascript, charts

I am new to Google Chart and I am trying create a dynamic pie chart in the dynamic webproject(Java EE). I have read the tutorial (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries) and copy the pie chart code in the google code play ground.

```
function initialize() 
{
    // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
    // Specify that we want to use the XmlHttpRequest object to make the query.
    var opts = {sendMethod: 'xhr'};
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A%3AB&key=0Aq4N8GK8re42dHlGMG0wM00tdE5PVjJZellXTEhFNEE&gid=0&headers=-1', opts);

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response)
{
    if (response.isError()) 
    {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true});
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

But it is not working and there is no piechart. Could please tell me where is the problem. My spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aq4N8GK8re42dHlGMG0wM00tdE5PVjJZellXTEhFNEE
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it sends the OPTION request instead of the correct GET. It is because you use the `opts` parameter, remove it and everything will work fine.

Also you can find a note about this parameter here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#Query

`opt_options
    [Optional, Object] A map of options for the request. Note: If you are accessing a restricted data source, you should not use this parameter.`

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

            function initialize() {
                // removed the `var opts...` line
                var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A%3AB&key=0Aq4N8GK8re42dHlGMG0wM00tdE5PVjJZellXTEhFNEE&gid=0&headers=-1');

                query.send(handleQueryResponse);
            }

            function handleQueryResponse(response) {
                if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                }

                var data = response.getDataTable();
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```